# Send HTTP Request CopyTo File to different document library - Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, sharepoint-rest-api, power-automate, flow

I am receiving a 400 Status error with my Power Automate app. I am unsure as to why, it seems there's an issue with my current code but unfortunately, I am unable to find it.

[image: Power Automate App Creation]

For Convert to PDF, the expression is:

```
replace(triggerBody()?['{Path}'], 'Working/', '')
```

And, for the Sent to HTTP Post I the expression is:

```
replace(toUpper(body('Get_file_metadata')?['Name']), '.DOCX', '.pdf')
```

Also, the status message output I receive is the following:

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "headers": {
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "x-ms-request-id": "8432469a0-d0c2-1100-8ji4-8e49fe65306e",
        "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
        "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
        "X-Frame-Options": "DENY",
        "Cache-Control": "no-store, no-cache",
        "Set-Cookie": "ARRAffinity=473c817130901edebb081d9a6ffdc67a5853b67fcdd59faa18c8da1e3d4f4c1a;Path=/;HttpOnly;Secure;Domain=sharepointonline-ase.azconn-ase.p.azurewebsites.net,ARRAffinitySameSite=473c817130fdc67901edebb081d9a6f a5853b67fcdd59faa18c8da1e3d4f4c1a;Path=/;HttpOnly;SameSite=None;Secure;Domain=sharepointonline-ase.azconn-ase.p.azurewebsites.net",
        "Timing-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "x-ms-apihub-cached-response": "true",
        "x-ms-apihub-obo": "true",
        "Date": "Tue, 20 Aug 2022 13:20:48 GMT",
        "Content-Length": "495",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Expires": "-1"
    },
    "body": {
        "status": 400,
        "message": "Server relative urls must start with SPWeb.ServerRelativeUrl\r\nclientRequestId: df231d17-ddff-3f7f-85ca-f0624ddda688\r\nserviceRequestId: 842329a0-d0b2-1080-8ec4-8e49fe26306b",
        "source": "https://consonto.sharepoint.com/sites/CONSONTOTESTUAT/_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('/DocumentLibrary1/Communications1/file.docx')/copyTo(strNewUrl=DocumentLibrary2/Communications2/file.pdf',bOverWrite=true)",
        "errors": [
            "-2147024809",
            "System.ArgumentException"
        ]
    }
}
```

Please let me know what I can do to change it.

Comment: Hi, did you try my solution given below? let me know if you need any further help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Existing file path URL in `getFileByServerRelativeUrl()` endpoint should be in below format:

```
/sites/siteName/libraryName/folderName/fileName.pdf
```

Use correct path in "Send an HTTP request to SharePoint" action and it should work for you.